# Como mostrar "aguarde, carregando dados" utilizando programação assincrona?

Tags: c#, winforms

Como posso utilizar programação assíncrona com Async e Await de modo que apareça no meio da grid "Aguarde carregando dados" enquanto busca dados no banco e preencha com o DataTable na Grid?

Programação em Windows Form e C#.

Answer (score 2):

Não sabendo como está estruturado o seu código em vez de responder usando *async* e *await* apresento uma solução usando a classe *Task*:

```
MostraAguarde(true);
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    LerDados();
});
task.ContinueWith(
t =>
{
    MostraAguarde(false);
},TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Crie o método `MostraAguarde(bool mostrar)` para apresentar a mensagem quando o parâmetro passado for `true` e retirar a mensagem quando for `false`.
Crie o método `LerDados()` onde será feita a leitura dos dados.

Penso que o código é de fácil entendimento:

É apresentada a mensagem.
Uma *Task* é criada para executar o método que lê os dados.
Quando o método `LerDados()` retorna, a *Task* é terminada e a mensagem retirada.

***EDIT***
Usando *await* seria qualquer coisa assim:

```
MostraAguarde(true);
try
{
    await LerDados();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ProcessErrors(e);            
}
finally
{
    MostraAguarde(false);
}
```

O método `LerDados()` terá de retornar `Task` ou `Task<T>`:

```
private Task LerDados()
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: No primeiro exemplo, a continuacao vai correr noutra thread, e portanto nao vai conseguir actualizar a UI. O correcto seria esperar pela task usando `await` para garantir o "flow" de contexto - `await Task.Run(LerDados); MostrarAguarde(false);`

Comment: "O método LerDados() terá de ser declarado como async" - nao necessariamente, o unico requisito e' que retorne uma `Task` ou `Task<T>`.

Comment: @dcastro Tem razão, `async` só é necessário se for usado `await` dentro do método. Em relação à primeira situação foi distração minha. Eu uso esta abordagem em WPF onde `MostraAguarde` é uma propriedade que, via Binding, faz hide/show do componente.